# Creating a dynamic dictionary name

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Very new to Python. I'm trying to dynamically create new dictionaries inside of a FOR LOOP with dictionary names that are derived from the first element of a LIST inside another list.

My goal is to end up with a data structure that looks like this:

```
router1 = {'Hostname': 'router1',
         'OS-Type': 'ios',
         'IP Address': '1.1.1.1',
         'Username': 'user1',
         'Password': 'cisco',}

router2 = {'Hostname': 'router2',
         'OS-Type': 'ios',
         'IP Address': '1.1.1.2',
         'Username': 'user2',
         'Password': 'cisco',}

sw1 = {'Hostname': 'sw1',
         'OS-Type': 'cat-os',
         'IP Address': '1.1.1.3',
         'Username': 'user3',
         'Password': 'cisco',}
```

These dictionaries would later be added to a LIST:

```
dictionary_list = [router1, router2, sw1]
```

Here's what my FOR LOOP currently looks like:

```
for i in range(len(device_list)):    
    dynamic_dictionary = {'Hostname': device_list[i][0],    
                          'OS-Type': device_list[i][1],    
                          'IP Address': device_list[i][2],    
                          'Username': device_list[i][3],    
                          'Password': device_list[i][4]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want specific names for those dictionaries if they become lists elements, anyway? You could as well call them X, Y, and Z, and you would have exactly the same list.

Comment: You can just make a list of dictionaries to make your life easier! Check if my answer helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My goal was to add the device specific dictionaries names only to the outer LIST. In other words, the outer LIST would look like this: "all_devices_list = [router1, router2, router3, sw1]"  This outer list would act as a sort of index for all individual devices. In other words, I find a device in the list, such as "sw1", and then I pull up the dictionary called "sw1', which has all device details. Maybe I'm just over-complicating things...

Comment: How does your `device_list` looks like, maybe that will help improve the answers below @Gus

Answer (score 1):

For your for loop,

```
# Python3 code to iterate over a list 
dict_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]] 
host_list = []
# Using for device_loop 
for i in device_list:
    host_dict = {'Hostname': i[0], 'OS-Type': i[1], 'IP Address': i[2], 'Username': i[3], 'Password': i[4]}
    host_list.append(host_dict)
```

What did we do, in place of using the older style of using the index in the array we replaced it with an iterator. There are multiple ways to iterate over different types of data in Python. Read up on them here: [loops in python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_for_loop.htm)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: `list` is the name of a built-in function. Do not use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Why not append the dictionaries you are creating to a list right away. In addition, define the list of keys before hand, so that you can append the dictionary while iterating over the list of keys

```
li = []
keys = ['Hostname', 'OS-Type', 'IP Address', 'Username', 'Password']
for i in range(len(device_list)):
    dct = {}
    for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
        dct[key] =  device_list[i][idx]
    li.append(dct)
```