# How to dynamically (i.e through program) change name of a Data dictionary to a dynamically obtained vaiable

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, dynamic-programming, rename

I am using python 3.9.6 in Windows 10.

Similar earlier questions at
(1) [Creating a dynamic dictionary name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55778701/16830063)
and
(2) [How to obtain assembly name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59613423/16830063)

were different and do not solve my problem.

My data dictionary(dynamically created):

```
pcm30={'ABB': '-0.92', 'ZYDUSWELL': 2.05}
```

Dynamically obtained new dictionary name "pCh0109" is in variable z

I have to create different dictionaries to create a data frame.

Now I want to dynamically (i.e through programming) change the name of the dictionary from
`'pcm30'`
to
`'pCh0109'`.

The digits in the new name of the dictionary ('pCh0109') indicate the time of creation of the particular dictionary.

How to do it?
Will be grateful for assistance and help.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you don't try this unless you **absolutely** have to, but here's the simplest approach to do that:

```py
pcm30 = {'ABB': '-0.92', 'ZYDUSWELL': 2.05}

globals()['pCh0109'] = globals().pop('pcm30')

# Your IDE might glare at you here, but it'll work out without errors at runtime
print(pCh0109)
```

Instead I suggest to try this approach - use a dictionary if possible. This will turn out *much* safer for all. Example below:

```py
def my_func():
    d = {}
    pcm30 = {'ABB': '-0.92', 'ZYDUSWELL': 2.05}

    d['pCh0109'] = locals().pop('pcm30')

    print(d['pCh0109']['ABB'])
    # -0.92
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is a complete side track. How the variable 'pCh0109' will come in d['pCh0109']. I am not doing it manually.  "pCh0109" is in variable z obtained dynamically. I want to know code for doing it.

Comment: I apologize if it's a side track, but I guess the question wasn't really clear to me

Comment: OK.  z= "pCh0109" ; pcm30={'ABB': '-0.92', 'ZYDUSWELL': 2.05}. Now I want to achieve that "pCh0109" ={'ABB': '-0.92', 'ZYDUSWELL': 2.05} through coding.

Comment: Your problem statement does not make sense. You cannot assign to a string value - it has to be a variable or some kind of dict object for example.

Comment: rv.kvetch My apologies from bottom of my heart. After several attempts, your suggestion seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, apologies if I came across as a bit harsh earlier, but I honestly didn't understand what you were wanting to do. However, I'm glad you were able to get everything working at last.

Comment: Also, while technically not required, would certainly appreciate if you accept my answer if it helped you out. Thanks